# Spring XML list of beans

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'd like to do something like

```
<bean id="xxx" class="yyy">
    <property name="list">
        <list>
            <ref bean="bean1" />
            <ref bean="bean2" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The beans "bean1" and "bean2" are two different implementations of an interface I. However, they belong to different classes. Does anyone know how I can do this? I have no problem constructing a list of Strings and a list of Integers. Why can't I construct a list of beans?

Thanks,
ktm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The beans "bean1" and "bean2" are two different implementations of an interface I. However, they belong to different classes. Does anyone know how I can do this?

It should work.  Try it.

(There should be no runtime type problem here because the runtime type of the list is the raw type of the implementation class used.)

> I have no problem constructing a list of Strings and a list of Integers. Why can't I construct a list of beans?

I think you are assuming that it won't work without trying it.

Comment: You're right. I did it again and it worked... (It didn't work the first time.) Perhaps it was necessary to put <list value-type="zzz">? I didn't have that set before.

Comment: @ktm5124 You don't need value-type if you are using Java 5 and define list in class yyy as List<zzz>.

Comment: @Ritesh - yes, I think so.  But if you just define it as `List<?>` you shouldn't.